# DirectoryExists("c:temp\\foo") returns true when directory doesn't exist!

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

OK, I got bit by something that seems a tad weird. I realize it was my mistake to not format the pathname correctly, but I would expect the following test to return false, especially since the folder did not exist.

```
DirectoryExists("C:temp\\foo")
```

but in fact, it returns true even though the directory does not exist!

The code should be

```
DirectoryExists("C:\\temp\\foo")
```

Can someone explain to me why I get a false positive from the first version? I would expect it to return false or throw an exception perhaps, but not return true.

Comment: I guess I should specify that this is C# under .NET!

Comment: What is `DirectoryExists`? That is not a standard .NET library function. It could be `Directory.Exists(path)`, but there is no `DirectoryExists` function.

Comment: I neither see any reason for it to return **true**. I'm curious about it. By the way, just in case you don't know, you could also write `Directory.Exists(@"C:\temp\foo");` while getting rid of the escape sequences.

Comment: @Adam Robinson - there is a [`DirectoryExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.directoryexists.aspx) method on the `IsolatedStorageFile` class. Still, even that shouldn't return `true` for this path. Probably a third party method that has not been properly tested.

Comment: Sorry, I typed this up rather hurriedly. I did mean to write 'Directory.Exists" as part of the System.IO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This API is behaving properly but often appears incorrect the first time you encounter this behavior. Omitting the `\` after the volume letter has special semantics.  It will replace the volume specifier with value passed into the last call to `SetCurrentDirectory` for that volume.  How this is remembered is discussed here

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363806(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363806%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

In this case the last value passed in was either `c:\` or the current directory simply hadn't been set.  Hence the call actually became the second version

```
Directory.Exists("c:\\temp\\foo")
```

This correctly evaluated to true

Why this happens for `Directory.Exists` is that deep, deep down in the function it uses [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28VS.85%29.aspx) which relies on this behavior (see the linked documentation).

Comment: But the directory didn't exist! (as far as I can tell) Even if it "fixed" the volume and pathname for me, it should still have returned false, right? The reason why this came up was because the code incorrectly thought a directory existed when in fact it did not. Can you link to where these semantics are explained? I'm not sure I get it yet.

Comment: If I sandbox this, it behaves how I would expect. However, in my production code, I most likely get a false positive because the current directory results in a condition where the directory in question exists somehow.